# How do I backup my Github repositories to a local disk daily?

Tags: github

I want to backup my organization's 100+ repository(with all branches) to my NAS device every day.

For example, I use `velero` to backup Kubernetes cluster. I'm looking for a github repository backup tool that serves a special purpose like `velero`.

Do you know of a tool for this?

Comment: Are you just looking to back up the repository contents, or all of the appurtenant information on GitHub as well (e.g., issues and pull requests)?

Comment: That's right. I want to repository contents with all branches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to back up the repository contents, then you can simply do this with `git clone --mirror URL`.  That will result in a bare clone with all your branches, which should be an exact copy of the remote repository.

If you have many repositories in an organization, you can create a script that uses the [List Organization Repositories API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories) to iterate over those repositories and clone them.  If you're only doing this once a day, it shouldn't cause too many problems for your rate limits.

Also note that GitHub backs up your repositories as well, so the likelihood of data loss is very low.